# age old dilema to have multiple versions of jquery on a page not conflict?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, conflict

so I keep running into the same issue, and I've tried reading through many solutions but can't seem to find something that works.  Essentially, I need to know of an easyish way to have it so my web page can load 2 different versions of jquery without conflicting... I know people keep recommending the "jquery noconflict" script, but I can't seeem to get that to work.

I have a 3d carousel that is using jquery 1.7, another thing below that is using 1.6, and a fader that uses 1.9.

Can someone please explain how I can get these all to play nicely on my web page?

Any input at all would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What is it about your different elements that can't run all on the same version of jQuery? I'd amend the plugins to work with the same version of jQuery. As it stands, you're loading and instantiating three versions of jQuery which is a LOT of overhead.

Comment: Have you tried the migrate plugin? You could use just jQuery 1.9 with the migrate plugin and everything should work. https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah, the trouble is that certain plugins only work using a certain version.  For example, the 3d carosuel will only work if it's using the 1.7 framework, not with the 1.9, etc.  It would be great if it all worked on 1.10, etc but I don't think that's the case which is why I'm trying to figure out a solution.

Comment: I'll also try the migrate plugin...

Comment: Somehow got them both to work by deleting the reference to the script for 1.6.... doesn't make any sense as to why but whatever.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use several versions of jquery on the same page, you could try to do something like this (not tested though)

```
<script src="jquery-1.6">
<script>
 $16=$
 $.noConflict();
</script>

<script src="jquery-1.9">
<script>
 $19=$
 $.noConflict();
</script>

<script>
  $16(document).ready(function($) {
    // now $ references to jquery 1.6
  })

  $19(document).ready(function($) {
    // now $ references to jquery 1.9
  })
</script>
```

as George Yates says, you should try to use only one version of jQuery, as more are too much overhead for the network.

Comment: hmm I get a syntax error in my code when I past that?  Yeah it would be best if I could get stuff to all run on the most recent version but I don't think that's an option :/